# Boolean mapping issue in Hibernate + MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

I know there are plenty of topics on this matter, but still, I couldn't solve my problem.

This is entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "messages")
public class Message
{
....
@Column(name = "read", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1)")
private boolean read;
....
public boolean isRead()
{
    return read;
}

public void setRead(boolean read)
{
this.read = read;
}
```

In `messages` MySQL table, `read` column is typed as `tinyint(1)`. Before saving object to table I set `setRead(true)`. When I'm saving object through Hibernate (`save()`) I get following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in 
your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 
'read, senderId, title) values ('ujhjg', 1, 1, 'W pustyni i w puszczy')'
```

I use `jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect` and tried few ways to solve my problem by changing annotations for boolean field, but none of them worked.

What's wrong with my mapping and how I can make it work?

Thanks for any help and your time ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word `read` is one of MySQLs reserved keywords. Check the table on [MySQL 5.0 Manual - 9.3. Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). Use a different name to avoid such situations.

Comment: The simpler answer I get to my questions, the more stupid I think I am :D Looks like you saved me a lot of time and stress. Cheers!